# Select Element on the basis of attribute

Tags: javascript

```
<ul>
  <li year='2014'> </li>  
  <li year='2014'> </li>
  <li year='2014'> </li>
  <li year='2015'> </li>
</ul>
```

Using Javascript how can I select those `li` item whose year attribute is set to 2014. I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("li[value=='2015']);
```

Comment: Use the prefix "data-" for your custom attributes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` for this:

In this case, the usage should be `document.querySelectorAll('li[year="2014"]')`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/njvwxsxd/

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: This would be a better answer if you included (not linked to!) an example of how to use it and explained what an attribute selector is.

Comment: @Quentin - Agreed. I should have included the code (done now). The OP looks like he knows about the attribute selector since his question mentions it, so not explaining that.